# Need help getting my webpage to look like my plan - html

Tags: html, css

i have made a plan for what i want my webpage to look like which i will link [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGH7n.png)

And im trying to create that with the following code HTML:

```css
body {
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
}
#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
}
#stage {
  float: left;
}
#LeaderBoard {
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  height: 180px;
}
#ChatRoom {
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  height: 180px;
}
#Options {
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <canvas id="stage" width="600" height="600">
    Canvas not supported
  </canvas>

  <div id="LeaderBoard" width="400" height="180">
    <h3>LeaderBoard<h3>
            <ul id="LeaderBoardList">
            </ul>
        </div>
  
        <div id="ChatRoom" width = "400" height = "180">
   <textarea width = "400" height = "180">
   </textarea>
   <input type="text">
        </div>
  
        <div id="Options" width = "400" height = "180">
   <button type="button">Left</button>
   <button type="button">Right</button>
   <button type="button">Up</button>
   <button type="button">Down</button>
   
   <button type="button">Music</button>
   <button type="button">SFX</button>
        </div>
  
    </div>
```

At the moment it currently looks like this [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDglc.png) And even worse when i resize the webpage the canvas will be on top and the rest below it

Im not worried about the buttons being alligned and stuff, just the divs and dimensions etc Would anyone be able to help me get it like my design, any help is appriciated

Comment: Try setting a fixed pixel width on the #container, that will prevent it from being responsive when the page is resized.

Comment: put a `div` around the left, right, up, and down buttons and assign them all an absolute position within that `div` to position them in the arrangement that you desire.

Comment: thanks moose, i added "    <div id="container" width = "1100"> " to the container, is that fixed? because it still messes up when i resize it

Comment: Okay, hang on, you are going about this the wrong way.  You are making this way more complicated than it has to be.  Please try to keep all of your CSS together in the CSS.  remove all the inline CSS (unless you have a really good reason to have it inline).  Next, please take some time and read and research and gain a VERY good understanding of the `position` property in CSS. also, please take time to understand the difference between `display: inline` and `display: block` and `display: inline-block`.  If you take the time to do that, you will have the answer automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width of the container needs to be fixed so it won't collapse down and the width and height you are trying to set inline in the HTML would need px for them to work that way. Better though to just set those in the external css. Also I removed the float from stage to let the others float left next to it. 
https://jsbin.com/quxebalewi/edit?html,css,output

```
<body>
  <div id="container">

    <canvas id="stage">
        Canvas not supported
    </canvas>

    <div id="LeaderBoard">
        <h3>LeaderBoard<h3>
        <ul id="LeaderBoardList">
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="ChatRoom">
        <textarea >
        </textarea>
        <input type="text">
    </div>

    <div id="Options">
        <button type="button">Left</button>
        <button type="button">Right</button>
        <button type="button">Up</button>
        <button type="button">Down</button>

        <button type="button">Music</button>
        <button type="button">SFX</button>
    </div>

  </div>
 </body>
```

and the css

```
body{
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
}

#container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1020px;
  height: 620px;
}

#stage{
  float: left;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

#LeaderBoard{
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  width: 400px;
  height: 180px;
}

#ChatRoom{
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  width: 400px;
  height: 180px;
}

#Options{
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  width: 400px;
  height: 180px;
}
```

Comment: great i can resize the window without everything messing up, im sure i can workout the rest if i keep trying so ill just approve this answer, thanks

Comment: Check out flexbox if you get the time, its a pretty great way to make sure everything aligns nicely. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/